# VS2017 ASP.NET Core Environment Development

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have problem when deploying ASP.NET Core on IIS Locally, I tried changing the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` from Development to Production in `Project Settings ->Debug->Environment Variables` and it seems not working at all when publishing through a folder `ProjectName->Publish->Folder->Publish` and I found out that everytime I publish the appsettings.{EnvironmentName}.json seems doesn't change from development to production.

Also it shows error:
[image: Error]

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

To change the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable value you need to edit the `launchSettings.json` for the project.

You should find it under the *Project* -> *Properties* node. Please note that you might have two or more values based on your *Run* profiles. I recommend changing both to get the same experience when using IIS Express / IIS and Kestrel.

Here is an example:

[image]

Also, as a reminder, you will need to add the following to your `ConfigurationBuilder` in `Startup.cs`:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
// Your config...
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

The setting you are talking about is used for Debugging the code within Visual Studio. If you are talking about truly "Publishing" locally you will need to either manually replace the environment in the launchSettings.json or create some kind of a build step (MSBuild target for example) to replace the value for you.

Comment: Hi! @Phil P., I already applied your suggestion, however its still give me the same error as development mode something... any other way?

Comment: @AlvinQuezon Do you have TRACE enabled in project settings?